# Is this combination of inheritance and protocols correct?

Tags: objective-c, inheritance, protocols

In the scenario in which I want to have a class intended to be a base class taking into account the need of the implementation of some base behavior directed by its subclases I figured out this:

**The protocol**

```
@protocol TheProtocol

@required

- (NSString *)someProperty;
- (void)someMethod:(NSString *)parameter;

@end
```

**The base view controller**

```
@interface BaseViewController : UIViewController
@end

@implementation BaseViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSAssert([self conformsToProtocol:@protocol(TheProtocol)], @"This view controller has to conform to TheProtocol.");
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    BaseViewController<TheProtocol> *castedController = (BaseViewController<TheProtocol> *)self;

    NSString *someProperty = [castedController someProperty];
    NSLog(@"%@", someProperty);        

    [castedController someMethod:@"Hello subclass!"];
}

@end
```

**Example of a controller which implements the protocol**

```
@interface Subclass1ViewController : BaseViewController <TheProtocol>
@end

@implementation Subclass1ViewController

#pragma mark - TheProtocol

- (NSString *)someProperty {

    return @"Subclass1";
}

- (void)someMethod:(NSString *)parameter {

    NSLog(@"%@", parameter);
}

@end
```

Is this pattern correct? I have a lot of concerns... The other option is to create a protected category instead of a protocol.

Comment: it depends on what you'd like to achieve... it looks that the `BaseViewController` _demands_ conforming the protocol, so I'm not seeing the logic in why it does not conform that protocol originally, and why it expects that from its subsets only... you may want to force the subset to override all methods for conforming the protocol, perhaps?

Comment: Yes @holex, that's the point.

Answer (score 1):

your pattern is right.

here is just quite similar solution to your idea but personally I would do this in my project for having the same purpose – so I don't need to cast the instance of the `BaseClass` inside the class, because in my idea the base class conforms the essential `DemandedProtocol` basically, but throws a runtime exception in every *required* method which has not been overridden in subset but tried to be invoked.

*NOTE: that is not worse or better than yours but different, anyone can use it for educational purpose in future.*

## DemandedProtocol.h

```
@protocol DemandedProtocol <NSObject>

@required

- (NSString *)someString;
- (void)setSomething:(id)something;

@optional

- (NSInteger)someInteger;

@end
```

## BaseClass.h

```
#import "DemandedProtocol.h"

#define ThrowOverrideIsMissingException @throw [NSException exceptionWithName:NSInternalInconsistencyException reason:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s has to be overridden in subset.", __func__] userInfo:nil]

@interface BaseClass : NSObject <DemandedProtocol> {

}

@end
```

## BaseClass.m

```
#import "BaseClass.h"

@implementation BaseClass

#pragma mark - <DemandedProtocol>

- (NSString *)someString {
    ThrowOverrideIsMissingException;
}

- (void)setSomething:(id)something {
    ThrowOverrideIsMissingException;
}

@end
```